# Build dependencies with apt-get build-dep for Linux-image-4.14

Tags: apt, kernel, dependencies

I need to install the dependencies for a Linux 4.14 kernel in Ubuntu Server 18 to build a patched kernel. My current one is 4.15

Even after removing the comments and activating the source repositories in sources.list the desired package can't be found.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-4.14-generic
```

I suspect either the name of the image is wrong or my sources.list is missing an entry for this task. I followed [this guide](http://forum.arcadecontrols.com/index.php/topic,158903.msg1671836.html#msg1671836).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Why do you want to use the 4.14 kernel?  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (releases are *yy.mm* in format, so 18 could mean 18.04 LTS or 18.10 as it's not specific) comes with 4.15 which is supported by Canonical for 5 years from release (*longer if you use ESM*). 4.14 is not supported in Ubuntu thus you'll have to patch it yourself which is not good security-wise if you're not skilled enough to do it.  Are you ready for this?

Comment: Your concern is absolutely right. I don't have the experience or skills for this, but since this will be an "offline machine" which sole purpose will be playing "retroPie" I'll risk to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this was hard to find, I blame my low experience with this but I got it working by installing these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source build-essential kernel-package libssl-dev ncurses-dev xz-utils libssl-dev bc
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt build-dep linux`
worked for me. Found it here:
https://git.sceen.net/rbraun/debian_on_asus_c101pa.git/tree/README